# I wanted to add data in pre formated Excel sheet using php

Tags: php, excel, append, addition

I wanted to append data in the pre formated excel sheet that is basically header footer in the excel sheet I wanted to append the contents. And will create many files dynamically.

Comment: So have you looked for any of the myriad of PHP libraries such as [PHPExcel](https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) that will help you to do this?

Answer (score 1):

A simple workaround is:

- create a html table with the formatting you need
- add values in php to the table (or generate table with php)
- save file as .xls (filled with content from html table)
- open file (will show formatted table in Excel)

Reason:

- handling XLS files is very complex and many libraries have big limits (only available on windows servers....)
- html table saved as .xls can be opened in Excel.

Comment: `html table saved as .xls is basically a valid minimum structure of a XLS file` B****cks.... MS Excel has an HTML importer which it can use, which means that it can read this though some versions of MS Excel will complain that you're lying to it; that's not the same as html being a minimum structure of an xls file

Comment: It works well, also for Doc files, clients are using for years without  any complains.

Comment: You will start to get complaints as your clients move to more recent versions of MS Excel; because you're creating a file whose format doesn't match that expected by an xls extension..... but to describe `html table saved as .xls is basically a valid minimum structure of a XLS file` is totally false, and totally disingenuous

Comment: Thanks for the update, i changed the text to be more accurate. In essence it still works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks I have found the way PHPExcel is a good library.
In order to get PHPExcel http://www.codeplex.com/PHPExcel working with CodeIgniter, there are a few steps you must take to ensure compatibility with CodeIgniter's naming standards.

1: Class names must match the file names. PHPExcel has a few files(such as PHPExcel/IOFactory.php) that have names like PHPExcel_IOFactory. Change these names by removing the "PHPExcel_" part. These constructors in these files must be public in order for CI to access them.

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->load->library('phpexcel');
$this->load->library('PHPExcel/iofactory');

$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setTitle("title")
                 ->setDescription("description");

// Assign cell values
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1', 'cell value here');

// Save it as an excel 2003 file
$objWriter = IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
$objWriter->save("nameoffile.xls");
```